# How can my jQuery function work consistently every time I resize the window?

Tags: jquery, resize, window

I have a function with different events assigned to different window widths. With my code, every time I resize the browser window, this function gets triggered. However, the behavior is strange:

. When I open the browser window at < 1025, the toggle works fine. But if I resize the window slightly, the toggle stops working. If I resize again, the toggle works again. It keeps going like that.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is have the mouse over > 1024, and the toggle at < 1025.

What am I doing wrong? Here's my code:

```
<body>

<style>

#dynamicbutton {
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

#dynamiclist {
    display: none;
    }

</style>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    function cresnavmaster() {

    if ($(window).width() > 1024) {

    $("#dynamicbutton").mouseover(function(){                         
        $("#dynamiclist").show();
        });

    $("#dynamicbutton").mouseout(function(){                          
        $("#dynamiclist").hide();
        });    


}

if ($(window).width() < 1025) {   

    $("#dynamicbutton").click(function(){                         
        $("#dynamiclist").toggle();
        });

}

}

cresnavmaster(); // Calls function when the page first loads

var resizelistener; // Adds short delay each time browser window is resized

$(window).resize(function(){
   clearTimeout(resizelistener);
   resizelistener = setTimeout(function(){
   cresnavmaster();
   },500);
});  

});

</script>

<div id="dynamicbutton">Dynamic Button</div>

<ul id="dynamiclist">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>


</body>
```

Comment: Your code seems to work properly on my side. It executes cresnavmaster() everytime I resize the window. Try to put an alert on top of the function to verify. What events are you calling inside the if statement?

Comment: Here's my code...

Comment: Thanks Jerdine. I updated my code above to better explain the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine but because you have 2 if statements instead of an if else. You are always checking both if statements every time the event is triggered. Therefore if the second if statement is true, it will always over write what you have done is the first if statement 
Try this:

```
if ($(window).width() > 1024) {
    // different events here
}

else if ($(window).width() < 1025) {   
    // different events here
}

}
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. Anyway, I updated my code above to better explain the issue. Thanks Zachary for your help.

Comment: Have you tried taking your if statements out of the cresnavmaster? It seems like the function will work upon first load but after you resize it is unable to find your conditions. I may be wrong as I am unable to test it. Try just having the if statements always readable and set a different condition to active them. Like if a boolean is true do the mouse over else do toggle. And change the boolean value when it's resized